# How did EFCore lose my "undeletable" data, and how can I re-attach it to the database?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-6

I am using `net6.0` (C# 10.0) with Entity Framework 6.0.1.

I have a 1:1 relationship between an `Parent` and `Child` models. Each share the same primary key (standard split-table design):

```
    modelBuilder.Entity<Parent>()
      .HasOne(fb => fb.Child)
      .WithOne(i => i.Parent)
      .HasForeignKey<Child>(s => s.Id)
      .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
```

Neither model should ever be deletable in practice (on a production server). As a way of guarding against this, I have implemented my `DbContext` to throw an exception if the relationship is severed, or either of the models is deleted:

```
  private static readonly List<Type> DeletePreventedModels = new List<Type>() {
    typeof(Parent), typeof(Child)
  };

  private void UpdateChanges() {
    // Prevent deletion of any protected models
    foreach (EntityEntry entry in ChangeTracker.Entries()) {
      if (entry.State != EntityState.Deleted) continue;
      Type t = entry.Entity.GetType();
      if (DeletePreventedModels.Any(mt => mt.IsAssignableFrom(t))) {
        var id = (entry.Entity is IStringKeyData d) ? d.Id : null;
        throw new ArgumentException($"{t.Name} {id} cannot be deleted");
      }
      if (t.IsAssignableTo(typeof(Parent)) && entry.State != EntityState.Unchanged) {
        Parent fb = (Parent) entry.Entity;

        if (fb.Child == null) throw new NullReferenceException($"Parent {fb.Id} had null child");
      }
    }
  }

  public override int SaveChanges() {
    UpdateChanges();
    return base.SaveChanges();
  }

  public override Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(
    bool acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken = new()
  ) {
    UpdateChanges();
    return base.SaveChangesAsync(acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, cancellationToken);
  }
```

I have taken this heavy-handed approach because I have been **losing Child data**. Specifically, I am finding rows missing from the MySQL table. There is nothing else which edits (or even accesses) the table, and I cannot figure out where these deletions are coming from. I know the data was originally present based upon database backups.

In attempts to correct the problem, I have added some code to the `Parent` class which is run after the model is loaded from the database (which does `.Include(p => p.Child)` btw).

```
  internal async Task FixChild(MyDataContext context) {

    if (Child == null) {
      this.Child = new Child() { Id = this.Id, Parent = this };
      if (context.Entry(Child).State == EntityState.Detached) {
        context.Attach(Child);
      }

      await Child.RestoreFromBackup(context);

      context.Log.Warning("[UPDATE] EMPTY CHILD {state} {id}",
        context.Data.Entry(Child).State, Id);

      await context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
 }
```

When this code runs, the broken children are successfully detected and restored from the backup. The child starts in the detached state, and then shows the `Modified` state (based on the log statement) once the `RestoreFromBackup` function runs. However, when we hit the SaveChanges line, I get:

```
The database operation was expected to affect 1 row(s), but actually affected 0 row(s);
```

There are no other warnings/errors in the logs. The restored child data seems complete, in that I can log the restored object and it matches the database backup (the database structure has not been changed since the backup).

In summary:

- How do I prevent the Child data from being lost?
- How do I properly save the restored Child data?

Comment: Have you considered adding delete trigger to the child table? You could also get user info or context to identify which sql account is deleting those records.

Comment: Hm, reading up on delete triggers now. I don't have any logs (unless they're in SQL?) for the userID. Rather, much of the database work is done on a background thread. I know roughly when the deletions happen, but can't find anything in my server logs that explains them (and this "deletion protection" code was already in-place). That said, I'm not logging every SQL statement.

Comment: You better analyze your code and try to find occurrences where Parent.Child can be set to null. Maybe even in Parent's constructor? Try what breaks when you make the property setter private. Don't try to work around an apparent bug. Also, prevent setting entire Parent entities as "Modified".